# Measure SMS consume by month

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to Salesforce Marketing, i want to discover how to check the SMS messages sent by month.

I need to prevent the organization to consume more SMS messages than what is stated in the company contract with Salesforce.

Is there a tool or API method inside Marketing Salesforce that shows the number of SMS messages sent and the remaining SMS messagens that can be sent?

Thank´s in advance
Angelo Rigo

Comment: there is a monthly account summary sent every month that details this

Comment: Thank you EazyE . How can i check before the end of the month ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to check the number of SMS sent in SMS Account Summary report in Analytics Builder, but it might not give you the exact clarity in terms of your Super Message consumption (which is the measure of your account utilization used by Salesforce). While each email sent costs you one single Super Message, the metrics are different for SMS.

This is based on two factors:

- when did your Salesforce Marketing Cloud subscription start
- to which country has the specific SMS been sent

You can always find the different multipliers in tables available on [this page](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/sfmc/sms-ratio-updates/).

To give you an indication of the differences, an SMS sent to Colombia costs 2 Super Messages, while one sent to Russia costs you 415.

For time being, the exact numbers on Super Messages consumption can only be provided by your Account Executive.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked from my MC account. You can use SMS Account Summary report in Analytics Builder to check the SMS sends.

In the report result, the MessageCountBySendType row will have the count detail for each type you need.

To check before the end of the month, when you create the report, you select Custom at the date range and put the date time you wish to have.

Salesforce uses "Super Messages" to charge you through your send (via Email, SMS, Push, etc..) so the number of SMS you will be able to send will be based on this. In case you are curious how many remaining Super Messages you have, you would need to reach out to your AE.